# how to generate a query for bring points in a radius in postgis

Tags: postgis

My question is how to calculate the radius from a point for all the locations that are in this radius? I am trying but always the query finds locations out site from the radius. This is an example:

[image: radius query]

the query I am using is:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Property"
WHERE "Property"."DeletedAt" IS NULL
    AND ((ST_DWithin(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(43.628123412124616, -116.19140625), 4326)::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point("Latitude", "Longitude"), 4326)::geography, 25730.9, true)))
```

Comment: It can be problem of different EPSG of layers. Propably your raster is 3857 from google/osm or diffrrent source and you are searching your points with epsg 4326. When you translate one to other there can be a huge diffrence - bigger for areas close to poles.

Answer (score 0):

`ST_POINT` takes longitude then latitude, so you should swap the two parameters. [see the doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html)